# "Cannot create a server using the selected type" Eclipse juno on Windows xp

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I am using eclipse juno on Windows xp with jdk1.6.0_23 and Tomcat 7.0.I was able to run web projects very well a until few days back.But now when I tried to run a web project it was showing some "bootstrap.jar" not found so i deleted all the tomcat Run Environment in servers tab below.Then when I tried to create again it shows "Cannot create a server using the selected type" when I google i found solutions only for linux,unix os But not WinXP :( How to solve this problem on Windows xpo thanks in advance

Comment: What was the selected type?